# Gremlin finding all connected paths is taking for ever

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

**Test 1: TinkerPop Modern**

Query:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").as("from")
.repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from", "to"))
.emit(hasLabel("software"))
.hasLabel("software")
.project("p","data")
.by(path())
.by(select(last, "from", "to").by("name"))
```

Executed in 0.20145893096923828 seconds

```
{'data': {'from': 'marko', 'to': 'lop'}, 'p': [v[1], v[3]]}
{'data': {'from': 'marko', 'to': 'ripple'}, 'p': [v[1], v[4], v[5]]}
{'data': {'from': 'vadas', 'to': 'lop'}, 'p': [v[2], v[1], v[3]]}
{'data': {'from': 'vadas', 'to': 'ripple'}, 'p': [v[2], v[1], v[4], v[5]]}
{'data': {'from': 'josh', 'to': 'ripple'}, 'p': [v[4], v[5]]}
{'data': {'from': 'josh', 'to': 'lop'}, 'p': [v[4], v[3]]}
{'data': {'from': 'peter', 'to': 'lop'}, 'p': [v[6], v[3]]}
{'data': {'from': 'peter', 'to': 'ripple'}, 'p': [v[6], v[3], v[4], v[5]]}
```

---

**Test 2: data/grateful-dead.xml** [sample data](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#barrier-step)

Query:

```
g.V().hasLabel("song").as("from") 
.repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from", "to")) 
.emit(hasLabel("artist")) 
.hasLabel("artist") 
.project("p","data") 
.by(path()) 
.by(select(last, "from", "to").by("name"))
```

**TAKES FOR EVER TO RUN! :(**, How can I improve my query time, any mistakes that I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Loaded into TinkerGraph? On my machine, it takes about 9 seconds to find all 124,285 paths. That's about 14 deduplicated paths per milliseconds - not too bad in my opinion.

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('data/grateful-dead.xml')
==>null
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:808 edges:8049], standard]
gremlin> traversal =
......1>   g.V().hasLabel("song").as("from").
......2>     repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from", "to")).
......3>       emit(hasLabel("artist")).
......4>     project("p","data").
......5>       by(path()).
......6>       by(select(last, "from", "to").by("name")); []

gremlin> traversal.clone().count()
==>124285

gremlin> clock(10) { traversal.clone().iterate() }
==>9013.734481099998
```

Comment: [CONSOLE]
**traversal = MY_QUERY; []**
*"traversal.clone().count()"* took 15 seconds and 
*"clock(10) { traversal.clone().iterate() }"* took about 3mins


*i3 with 4gb RAM on Ubantu 16*

Comment: [SERVER]
**traversal = MY_QUERY; []**
*"traversal.clone().count()"* took 14 seconds and 
*"clock(10) { traversal.clone().iterate() }"* took about 2 mins 20 seconds


*i3 with 4gb RAM on Ubantu 16*

Comment: [SERVER] **MY_QUERY** without *traversal =* takes for every to run, I killed the task after 8mins+

Comment: Anything in the server logs? What TinkerPop version are you using? What's your underlying Graph DB?

Comment: Gremlin 3.3.1
NEO4J Community 3.3.1
(both have the same version somehow)

ill look up the logs